# What handling differences should I expect when moving from a bike to a Recumbent Trike?

Tags: recumbent, tricycle, handling

I have been riding a normal bicycle, I just purchased a used Sun EZ-3 SX Delta Trike. I only have about a dozen miles on it on a few short trips.

There is an [answer here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/sun-ez3-trike-gearing/18213#18213) indicating some of the issues common to the model. Some of the things I have noticed. I am not complaining, just wondering what else to expect, and how the model/style impacts handling.

- Corner slower, you can't lean into them.
- Power to the right rear tire, makes the trike steer left.
- A bit of a wobble when coasting down hill, keep the speed under control
- Comfortable seating
- I can see where I am going without lifting my head unnaturally
- You can go slow (or stop) without tipping over

There are obvious issues that are inherent in a bigger heavier unit, like transporting in a car, or peddling up hill.

What handling differences are inherent to all tricycles?  What are unique to specific designs?

Comment: You can stop without tipping over on a two wheel bike. How much slower can one go?

Comment: @ojs Ignoring those poeple who can balance a two wheeled bike, at a full stop with their feet on the peddles, I was referencing that anyone can pedal at the speed of a snail and not fall over.

Comment: I think your list is a good summary, but your question is far too broad. There's not a lot of commonality between the Overzealous trike world speed record holder and a Roman upright tandem trike. Your trike is a long wheelbase delta, so the handling differences are mostly specific to that design. For example, a short wheelbase tadpole is likely to corner and stop faster than an upright bike, and much faster than your delta.